# How to use the @capacitor-community/file-opener on Apache Cordova movil App?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I was searching information about how to use this library @capacitor-community/file-opener but i could not find any informacion. Only i fund the documentacion, however, It is not explicitly to understand to me. Therefore, can some one give some example please?
Thanks!